# Anonymous (non-logged-in) users do not see any links to new blog posts

Tags: feature-request, blog-overflow, community-bulletin

Now that blog posts go into the community bulletin instead of the main header, and given that the community bulletin is (apparently) not shown to anonymous users, it would appear that anonymous users do not see any links to blog posts when they are published.

Given that blog content is likely to be more relevant to a broader audience that may not be as familiar with the site, and in fact blog posts may be a good way to get people interested in the site in the first place, I think it would make sense to have some way for blog posts to appear for non-logged-in users.

Can the community bulletin show events and blog posts, but hide meta posts, for non-logged-in users perhaps? Or, is there another solution we can use?

Comment: Goes into the community bulletin rather than the main header - since when did this happen?

Comment: @tombull89 blog posts haven't been shown in the site header for months.

Comment: Ah - the last blog post for ServerFault (where I frequent the most) was in Feburary. Probably why I havent noticed.