# It's time for the blogs to get some more site presence

Tags: feature-request, blog, blog-overflow

Currently the **only** way to navigate from a main site to its blog is from a link hidden all the way at the bottom of the page:

> [image: Let's play the 'Where's blog' game]

and that's it.  To a new user, or the public it's not very easy to see that there's an actual blog tied to the site, let alone any feed of recent blog posts.  I have two major suggestions to add to each site that has established its own blog.

### 1. Move the blog link to the very top

> [image: review chat meta help]

Most sites that I've visited, and has a blog, has a link to it directly above. Please let's do the same.

### 2. Advertise recent/popular posts on the side of the site

Stack Overflow already does this with Careers 2.0:

[image: amazing jobs]

It has direct links to job listings.  I propose we do the same thing only with the blogs.  It'll link recent and most popular posts on the side of the site to catch the attention of site users and public visitors.

Can we please give a little more love to the promotion of our site blogs?

Comment: having the blog link on top, iirc when there was a new post, was the default behaviour at some point, wasn't it?

Comment: Doesn't 2 already happen in the "Community bulletin" section?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist only when a new blog post is posted and isn't permanently there.  Since most sites don't blog every day or even every week, it's often missed.  I'd like to have something more consistently there.

Comment: The links in the header serve the primary purpose of the site, namely, asking and answering questions. The blogs are nice, but they are tangential to the focus. I don't want the extra clutter.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins then, by your criteria, the chat link shouldn't be there.

Comment: I think it serves as well, when it is used to help a user understand a problem that can't be fully developed in comments. Admittedly it is the least-used link for me, but it serves a minor purpose. EDIT: TBH, I'd be okay with removing it, too. ;)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, it was. It even had a flashy "new" badge in red next to it. They ditched it in favor of moving it to the community bulletin AFAIR.

Comment: FWIW, the length of time a new blog post is displayed in the bulletin *can* be adjusted. See: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3780/programmers-blog-visibility/3919#3919

Comment: Yes, please, and thanks. The way things stand right now, the blog might as well not exist. I've been a member on this site for years but only discovered that there was a blog relatively recently.

Comment: @Shog9 and Kronos - users who aren't logged in (i.e. those who may be most interested in general-audience blog posts!) [don't even see the community bulletin board](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179974/anonymous-non-logged-in-users-do-not-see-any-links-to-new-blog-posts). Anonymous users may literally have no idea the blog exists.

Comment: I had made a [more general feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135654/how-can-we-improve-the-community-bulletin) regarding the visibility of the Community Bulletin (because blogs/featured posts were no longer as visible). Feel free to borrow any ideas from there.

Comment: That's funny, I wasn't even aware there was a blog until reading this post and I've been a member for 8 months...

Comment: @Xarcell that's the problem that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @nhinkle I would like to make the link at least visible to the public, if not these "announcements" as well.

Comment: +1, the blog could do with some more publicity. As @Xarcell said, many of us either don't know it or are simply vaguely aware of its existence and never visit.

Comment: There's a link in the footer? Who knew! In all seriousness though, I didn't know it was there. I sort of remember something at the top of the page a fairly long time ago but I'd no idea there was a permanent link...

Comment: +1 because I only knew blogs existed because of links to latest blog post in newsletters sometimes. Another +1 because I could never even find a link to the blog from the main site, and thus only went there on newsletter days. But -1 because you used neat red computer-generated rectangles instead of freehand circles. Net: +1

Comment: @BenLee I'll make them green next time.

Answer (score 4):

You can always make a [Community Promotion Ad](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5996/community-promotion-ads-2013), which will periodically show up on the site sidebar. [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5347/34364) is already doing this and is getting a few extra views from it.

Comment: That's more of a work around than it is a solution.

Comment: @Zane That depends on what you consider to be a solution. To me, if this is effective enough to get more views for the blog, than it is a solution.

Comment: I would consider a solution to OPs question for the site to make a change to increase the visibility of it's blog section.

Comment: @Zane I'm looking to have a more permanent/public solution

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there's a lot of support for making the blog more visible.

The one thing I'd point out is the low frequency of the posting on the blog.  There was a span of over two months in between the last two posts.  For a blog, that's a long time.  To put it in perspective, it's even longer than the time in between posts at Coding Horror.

This might backfire.  You have a nice prominent link to the blog, and hence more people will check it out, but nearly all of the time, there won't be a new post there.  People will check it less, and then it will just be clutter.

So, I'd recommend a couple of options:

- Notify the user of a new blog post in the StackExchange dropdown when they visit that site, or
- Add the link where you suggested, but also put something like a "new!" box next to it when there's a new post.

That way people won't be checking all the time only to see the same aging post.

Comment: We're looking to improve our time between blog posts, but part of the problem is that nobody k ows about it, which makes it difficult to recruit new bloggers.

Comment: +1 I really like your first suggestion of adding blog posts to the notifier box (but only as long as blog posts are very infrequent).